# Lit element css grid

Tags: css-grid, lit-element, lit-html

I'm implementing a (lit-element) webcomponent that has a css-grid that's specific per instance of the element. For now I set the grid-template property by the style attribute of the element, but as the grid can become quite big this attribute is also very large and maybe reaches some limits and certainly is not nice to read/validate in the HTML. What would be the correct way to do this?

Like:

```html
<div id="timeline" draggable="true" class="timeline year" style="grid-template: [years] &quot;dummy-group-cell _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021--- _y_2021---&quot; var(--default-height, 40px) [months] &quot;dummy-group-cell _m_2021-09 _m_2021-09 _m_2021-09 _m_2021-09 _m_2021-09 _m_2021-10 _m_2021-10 _m_2021-10 _m_2021-10 _m_2021-10 _m_2021-10 _m_2021-10&quot; var(--default-height, 32px) [data] [none] &quot;none - - - - - - - - - - - -&quot; var(--default-height, 60px) [none] &quot;none - - - - - - - - - - - -&quot; var(--default-height, 60px) [none] &quot;none - - - - - - - - - - - -&quot; var(--default-height, 60px) [none] &quot;none - - - - - - - - - - - -&quot; var(--default-height, 60px) [none] &quot;none - - - - - - - - - - - -&quot; var(--default-height, 60px) [footer] &quot;none - - - - - - - - - - - -&quot; 1fr [end] / [group] auto [_1635285600000] var(--width) [_1635372000000] var(--width) [_1635458400000] var(--width) [_1635544800000] var(--width) [_1635631200000] var(--width) [_1635721200000] var(--width) [_1635807600000] var(--width) [_1635894000000] var(--width) [_1635980400000] var(--width) [_1636066800000] var(--width) [_1636153200000] var(--width) [_1636239600000] var(--width) ;">
   ...
</div>
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/shadycss/scoping-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
      import {LitElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element@0.6.1/lit-element.js?module';

      import 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/paper-button@3.0.1/paper-button.js?module';

      class MyElement extends LitElement {
              
        static properties = {
          color: {type: String}
        };   
      
        firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
          super.firstUpdated(changedProperties);

          // todo: fix @apply https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/518
          window.ShadyCSS.styleSubtree(this);
        }
      
        render() {
          return html`
            <style>
              :host {
                --paper-button: {
                  background: ${this.color};
                }
              }
            </style>
            <paper-button style="color:${this.color}">Button</paper-button>
          `;
        }
      }

      customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
    </script>

    <my-element color="green"></my-element>
    <my-element color="red"></my-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more why you decided to set the grid styles like that rather than using a CSS selector or something?

Comment: Thanks for the response Alan. Because lit-element uses shadyCSS and this is documented here: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#dynamic-classes-and-styles

But, maybe I could use the strategy described there to create a separate style per instance (as my grid is different per instance as it depends on the config of the webcomponent).

Comment: @AlanDávalos: added a code snippet to demonstrate the shadyCSS issue with <style> tags in inside a shadow dom. The template will not be rendered per instance, the inline style is.

Comment: Thanks for adding the snippet, that gives some context to this, I'm guessing that you are using the Shadow DOM polyfill for either paper-* elements compatibility or IE support? Is there any chance you could use any more recent implementation of material?

Comment: @AlanDávalos: I'm just using lit element in the latest Chrome and, although I know it won't use the polyfills there, the doc says you should not use dynamic styles per instance in the style tag (see https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#dynamic-classes-and-styles).

Comment: Maybe I could also post it in the lit element slack for some inspiration...

Comment: You are definitely using a very old version. see for newer versions https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/